# Custom angular2 date format pipe that uses translations

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-translate, angular-pipe

first, this is what I would like to accomplish:

Let's say I have a model for a posting that contains a js Date object. Now, I would like to render the date in a custom, human readable format that does not show a date and time, but rather an offset from now (i.e. "just now", "about one hour ago", "about two hours ago" etc.).

I am new to both, TypeScript and angular2, but from what I read so far, the most elegant approach would be to use a custom pipe like that:

```
@Pipe({name: 'hrTime'})
export class HrTimePipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {

    }

    transform(val: Date): string {

        // Roughly check if that date is about one hour ago
        let now: Date = new Date();
        now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - 90);
        if (val > now) {
            return this.translate.instant("about_1_h_ago");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this approach is that TranslateService's `instant()` method doesn't make sure the translation file is loaded at the time this pipe is constructed or used. Therefore, my custom pipe currently just returns my translation key (since `instant()` doesn't find my translation).

For larger timegaps (i.e. more than a day ago), my pipe should internally just use the date format pipe, so returning a translation key that has to be piped into `translate` isn't really an option.

Do you have any suggestions? Is using a custom pipe the right approach for what I would like to accomplish?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the APP_INITIALIZER opaque token to provide the translations on app start. Look at [this](https://gist.github.com/M4R1KU/20359bd6bebfe0a9b0107d82ed729fbc) gist of mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dont care about have a external dependencie, why dont use the moment pipes, you have this implement in angular 2 https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment

Answer (score 0):

You could make it into an impure pipe and return an Observable. That way you can chain your pipe to the `async` pipe and have it work seamlessly.

That way you'd have three scenarios i think:
- the timegap is large: resolve with the date immediately
- the timegap is small and the translations have been loaded already: translate and resolve immediately
- the timegap is small and the translations are not ready yet: wait for the translations file to load and then resolve with the proper translation

Comment: I will also try this approach, but as far as I understood impure pipes should be avoided (especially in something like a list of postings) for performance reasons?

Comment: yes, the impure pipe might be called more often (on every component change detection) so there's more chance of a performance impact. You would have to evaluate how heavy the transformation is and how many times will be called on average. I wouldn't avoid it by default tho, don't ignore the tools you have ...